# SQL query returns me some row equal to 0 whereas it should not

Tags: sql

I've got these 3 tables:

___Kardex

```
|--------|---------|-------------|
| KDX_Id | KDX_VIP | KDX_Regular |
|--------|---------|-------------|
| 1      |      No |          No |
| 2      |      No |          No |
|--------|---------|-------------|
```

___BillableDatas

```
|--------|---------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_BookingId |
|--------|---------------|
| 1      |            99 |
| 2      |            99 | 
| 3      |           100 | 
|--------|---------------|
```

___Bookings

```
|--------|--------------|
| BOO_Id | BOO_ClientId |
|--------|--------------|
|     99 |            1 |
|    100 |            2 | 
|--------|--------------|
```

I want to loop into ___Kardex and count for each client:

- The number of bookings the client booked (containing in ___Bookings).
- The number of nights the client spent (containing in ___BillableDatas).

So I tried:

```
SELECT 
    KDX_Id, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(BOO_Id) 
        FROM ___Bookings
        WHERE KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId
    ) AS nb_bookings,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(BIL_Id) 
        FROM ___Bookings, ___BillableDatas
        WHERE ___Bookings.BOO_Id = ___BillableDatas.BIL_BookingId
        AND KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId
    ) AS nb_nights 
FROM  ___Kardex
```

My problem is: the query returns me all the rows in `___Kardex` whereas I would like only the one with `nb_bookings` or `nb_nights` >= 1.

Could you please help ?

Here the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1b497/1

The expected result is:

```
|--------|-------------|-----------|
| KDX_Id | nb_bookings | nb_nights |
|--------|-------------|-----------|
| 1      |           1 |         2 |
| 2      |           1 |         1 |
|--------|-------------|-----------|
```

Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, copy your subqueries in the `WHERE` and check if they are >= 1.

```
SELECT 
    KDX_Id, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(BOO_Id) 
        FROM ___Bookings
        WHERE KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId
    ) AS nb_bookings,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(BIL_Id) 
        FROM ___Bookings, ___BillableDatas
        WHERE ___Bookings.BOO_Id = ___BillableDatas.BIL_BookingId
        AND KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId
    ) AS nb_nights 
FROM  ___Kardex
WHERE
    (
        SELECT COUNT(BOO_Id) 
        FROM ___Bookings
        WHERE KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId
    ) >= 1
    OR
    (
        SELECT COUNT(BIL_Id) 
        FROM ___Bookings, ___BillableDatas
        WHERE ___Bookings.BOO_Id = ___BillableDatas.BIL_BookingId
        AND KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId
    ) >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT k.KDX_Id, 
            (SELECT COUNT(BOO_Id) 
             FROM ___Bookings b
             WHERE k.KDX_Id = b.BOO_ClientId
            ) AS nb_bookings,
            (SELECT COUNT(BIL_Id) 
             FROM ___Bookings b JOIN
                  ___BillableDatas bd
                  ON b.BOO_Id = bd.BIL_BookingId AND
                     k.KDX_Id = b.BOO_ClientId
           ) AS nb_nights 
     FROM  ___Kardex k
    ) k
WHERE nb_bookings > 0 OR nb_nights > 0;
```

Note other changes to the query:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify all column references, when you have more than one table in a query.

If you are using MySQL, you don't even need subqueries.  You can just put:

```
HAVING nb_bookings > 0 OR nb_nights > 0
```

at the end of your query.

Comment: I think it's even easier than this... I suspect the question is stated poorly, and it will be impossible to have a Booking without a valid Billing, such that the OP can just join the tables and group by the KDX_Id

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `JOINS` (i.e. `INNER JOIN`) but with proper explicit *JOIN* syntax :

```
select k.KDX_Id,t.nb_bookings, t1.nb_nights  
from ___Kardex k
inner join (
    select  BOO_ClientId, count(*) nb_bookings
    from ___Bookings
    group by BOO_ClientId
           ) t on t.BOO_ClientId = k.KDX_Id 
inner join (
     select b.BOO_ClientId, COUNT(bl.BIL_Id) nb_nights
     from ___Bookings b
     inner join  ___BillableDatas bl on bl.BIL_BookingId = b.BOO_Id
     group by b.BOO_ClientId
           ) t1 on t1.BOO_ClientId = k.KDX_Id;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1b497/16)

Answer (score 0):

```
select k.KDX_Id, COUNT(BOO_Id) as nb_bookings, COUNT(bd.BIL_Id) as nb_nights
from ___Kardex k
inner join ___Bookings b on k.KDX_Id = b.BOO_ClientId
inner join ___BillableDatas bd on bd.BIL_BookingId = b.BOO_Id
group by k.KDX_Id
```